# sql inner join not working for inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables like customer, items, manufacture, order, stock.. refer http://www.oninit.com/manual/informix/english/docs/gn7382/4366.pdf

I want to get the  first and last names of every person (and the city and state they live in) who has ordered something made by the company **Smith**. Include the description (from the stock table).

If I execute the first part as

```
select c.fname, c.lname, c.city, c.state from customer c join orders o using (customer_num)
join items i using(order_num)
join manufact m using(manu_code)  where m.manu_name = 'Smith' ;
```

I get 8 records which is correct, I further want the description from stock table for these records, so I created a join on stock table like

```
select c.fname, c.lname, c.city, c.state, s.description from customer c join orders o using (customer_num)
join items i using(order_num)
left join (manufact m join stock s on m.manu_code=s.manu_code) on m.manu_code = i.manu_code where m.manu_name = 'Smith';
```

Now, its giving me 24 records which I dont expect. **How do I write a nested query to get only 8 records?**

Stock schema [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iotWT.png)

Comment: Can you give the `stock` table structure ?

Comment: @NoorAShuvo its in the image

Comment: No links or pictures, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see from your stock table that, there are multiple `stock_num` for a `manu_code`. There are 3 `stock_num` for the corresponding manu_code for `m.manu_name = 'Smith'`

Thats why your query returns 8*3 = 24 rows.

To get the appropriate result, you can

```
select c.fname, c.lname, c.city, c.state, s.description
from customer c 
     join orders o using (customer_num) 
     join items i using (order_num) 
     join manufact m using (manu_code) 
     join (select description from stock group by manu_code) AS s ON s.manu_code = m.manu_code
where m.manu_name = 'Smith'
```

Comment: I know why I am getting this result and I dont have any condition for stock_num.

Comment: Then the description for all the `manu_code` for a `stock_num` is same?

Comment: Shouldnt matter

Comment: Then if there are 3 descriptions for `manu_code=A, stock_num=1, Description = Des1`, `manu_code=A, stock_num=2, Description = Des2` and `manu_code=A, stock_num=3, Description = Des3`, which description you want to show?

Comment: If it does not matter, you can join `(select description from stock group by manu_code) AS s` instead of `stock`. this should fixed your issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If it helped you, can you please upvote my answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

You have 24 stock items from the manufacturer.  You need to decide what you want to display.

Your query is doing what you want it to do.

I would say, though, that structuring the query without the nested join is simpler.  You also left out the `description`:

```
select c.fname, c.lname, c.city, c.state, s.description
from customer c join
     orders o
     using (customer_num) join
     items i
     using (order_num) join
     manufact m
     using (manu_code) join
     stock s
     using (manu_code)
where m.manu_name = 'Smith';
```

I also suspect that `stock` has some sort of `itemid` that you should also be joining on.

Comment: I just want description for those 8 records

Comment: @Mat . . . You do that by including the `description` in the `select`.